# OMS--Leaflet markers have different stack order after spiderfy

Tags: leaflet, maps, oms, markerspiderfier

#### our setup

We have an **L.map** with various layers of **L.markers** loading from a dynamic array of events spanning a monthly period. Many of the listed venues hold numerous events during any given period and hence we end up with numerous markers sharing locations that are very nicely spiderfied using the **OMS-Leaflet plugin (0.2.6)** we run from CDN

Each marker is put into one of several marker Layers depending on day of week or whether the event has been confirmed / expires e.g. here is one that falls on a weekend:

```
markerWeekEnd = L.marker([lat, lon], { %options% });
markerWeekEnd.addTo(map);
weekend.addLayer(markerWeekEnd);
oms.addMarker(markerWeekEnd);
```

It took me a while to figure out how to **stack the markers correctly** so that they shows up in a certain order (**1.** upcoming markers, **2**. other future date markers and **3**. any expired markers if applicable) using **zIndexOffset** as the **bringToFront()** method does not support L.markers.

​

#### the issue

We have everything loading and stacking as required and **it all works fine until** we **unspiderfy**/**spiderfy**. When the markers get re-spiderfied **the one that ends up on top is not the one initially displayed**.

I took a look at all the OMS issues, not just **OMS-Leaflet**  (i.e. also the **OMS version for Google Maps API v3**), and found a couple of closed ones that seemed to suggest a similar issue:

[OMS should remember original zIndex of marker #76](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/pull/76)
z-Indices reset #117 (previous fix closes this)

Now as far as I can tell the related fix for these appears to have been applied to **OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/1.0.2/oms.js** (also 1.0.3 now I imagine) but perhaps **not** the **OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/0.2.6/oms.js** version.

In any case our subsequent efforts to get around the issues described above did seem to address the zIndex somewhat but not overcome our stacking issue relating to OMS spiderfy.

​

#### what we tried

Decided to tweak my marker options to **retain the original zIndexOffset** settings `L.marker([lat, lon], {... zIndexOffset: mIndex, mDay: mDay})`  and to see if resetting the zIndex using the retained values could fix my stacking issue

```
// for both spiderfy & unspiderfy
oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) { 
   markers.forEach(function(marker) { zIndexCheck(marker); });
}
function zIndexCheck(marker){
   L.setOptions( marker, { zIndex: mIndex, zIndexOffset: mIndex });
}
```

Sadly **even though it seem to retain the zIndex values for markers** before and after the **unspiderfy**/**spiderfy**, the eventual marker that remains on top is **not the one that was there before**, **nor** the one with the highest **supplied zIndex count** (addListener for spiderfy).

I have re-created a stripped down version of our sites functionality on the following **jsfiddle** and **console logged the zIndexes** of the initial markers before and after the spiderfy:

```
Marker Title: 'London Socials #1 (1/2)' startTime:ENDED: 1st Feb zIndex:-10
Marker Title: 'London Socials #2 (14/2)' startTime:Fri 14th Feb zIndex:5054 (Active)
Marker Title: 'London Socials #3 (28/2)' startTime:Fri 28th Feb zIndex:2026
```

`#2` is the **active item** initially

**Spiderfy**

```
[London Socials #1 (1/2)]  index:990
[London Socials #2 (14/2)]  index:5027
[London Socials #3 (28/2)]  index:5013
```

**UnSpiderfy**

```
[London Socials #1 (1/2)]  index:990
[London Socials #2 (14/2)]  index:5027
[London Socials #3 (28/2)]  index:5013 (Active)
```

`#3` is now the **active item** after spiderfy/unspiderfy (see final elements below)

​
**Final marker element**

```
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-blue awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" 
title="London Socials #2 (14/2)" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(83px, 218px, 0px); 
z-index: 5218;"><i class=" fa fa-moon  icon-white"></i></div>

<div class="awesome-marker-icon-blue awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" 
title="London Socials #3 (28/2)" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(83px, 218px, 0px); 
z-index: 5218;"><i class=" fa fa-moon  icon-white"></i></div>
```

And this is as far as I got to, **unable to figure out how item 3 with a previously lower zIndex** (compared to item 2) managed to **end up on top** with a new **z-index: 5218** which just so happens to be the **same new z-index value** as for **item 2**!

​​​
I posted this as a bug on gitHub, but now I'm not so sure it is a bug with OMS-Leaflet. So am posting on here as well. Here's the fiddle showing the issues:

https://jsfiddle.net/magicmb/17j2z4gy/

​​​
Environment specific versions: 
leaflet.js (1.6.0), Leaflet.awesome-markers (2.0.2), OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet (0.2.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out it's not exactly a bug with OMS-Leaflet but more an issue
>   with Leaflet and how it handles z-Indexes

​

Here's an extract from a thread I discovered on [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115954/157392) that was answered by [YaFred](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35248/yafred) way back in Oct 2 '14 and still very much relevant today:

---

Until somebody finds a better solution, here what I would do ...

As you noticed, leaflet is using pixel position to set zIndex (in Marker.js)

```
pos = this._map._latLngToNewLayerPoint(this._latlng, opt.zoom, opt.center).round();
this._zIndex = pos.y + this.options.zIndexOffset;
```

What I suggest is to undo leaflet zIndex using setZIndexOffset()

Say you want to set zIndex = 100, you would do

```
var pos = map.latLngToLayerPoint(marker.getLatLng()).round();
marker.setZIndexOffset(100 - pos.y);
```

**There is a bit of a glitch**: you have to **do it every time the map is zoomed** :( `[EDIT: Spiderfied in our case!]`

Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/xewj5tbh/) (comment the code in adjustZindex() to see the difference)

---

​

**For my OMS Spiderfy case this was resolved by adding:**

```
function adjustZindex() {
    var markers = oms.getMarkers();
    for (var i = 0, len = markers.length; i < len; i ++) {
      var marker = markers[i];
      var latlng = marker._latlng, mIndexOffset = marker.options.mIndexOffset ;
      var pos = map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlng).round();
      marker.setZIndexOffset(mIndexOffset - pos.y);
    }
  }
  adjustZindex();
```

and then calling adjustZindex() from my spiderfy listeners

```
oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
    layersBring2Front(); 
    adjustZindex();
  });
```

So I guess whether [OMS should remember original zIndex of marker #76](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/pull/76) was resolved in the version of OMS-Leaflet is kinda irrelevant as in all probability it would not have solved our issue.